# Meson and NInja build system: specify where binaries are stored

Tags: build, prefix, ninja, meson-build

I have a project that needs to be built like this:

1. `./meson.py build`
2. `./ninja -C build install`

This works well.  The only thing is: the binaries are stored in (on Linux): `/usr/local/bin`. This would require me to input root password because the binaries are being written to a root-access folder, aka `/usr/local/bin`.

Is there a way to install the binaries in some folder in the `/user/home` directory, so that no passwords are required?

The thing is that everytime I debug and change something, the rebuilding process forces the binaries to be rewritten, which asks for password everytime.

This is what I tried:

1. Create a folder in home: `mkdir ~/projectbin`
2. Use ninja with `--prefix` option:  `./ninja -C --prefix=~/projectbin install`

This throws an error of unrecognized option `--prefix`.

I am new to `ninja` and `meson`, please let me know how to resolve this.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The way to pass an option to Meson is using the `-D` option. So to set the prefix, you should use `meson -Dprefix=$HOME/projectbin build`.

Note that you set this at configure time (ie when calling `meson`), not at build time (when calling `ninja`).